# Hide html input element until javascript loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-io

I have a form input (type='file') that I'm styling using [this JQuery plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_custom_file_input_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/).  Basically it overlies a new span over the input element as a mask of sorts and boxes it all up in a div.  The issue is that, for the second before the javascript loads, it displays the standard html input  box and button (unsightly).  My question is whether there is any to either

1) Hide the input element (while keeping it's clickable functionality)

OR

2) Hide the input element until the javascript kicks in to cover it up.

OR

3) Something that I haven't even thought of.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 100% CSS solution and doesn't require JS to check dimensions at runtime. The trick is to give the input a **huge** font-size, like `460px`, this will push any visible part out of a wrap element:

Ex:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:100px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;">
     Upload button <!-- this text will be shown -->
     <input type="file" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; font-size:460px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution.  I additionally made the background transparent and set the border to "none" and was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best way of doing this is by waiting until the DOM and javascript are fully loaded, so you set your input element to be hidden, then use `$(document).ready(function() {...})` to style your input when javascript is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS + Javascript.

HTML Example:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

CSS to hide the file:

```
input#file
{
    display: none;
}
```

after your javascript loads, run the method to customize the input and run a show command to make the input visible after the customizations:

```
$('input#file').customFileInput().show();
```

With this way, your input file will not appear until your javascript has completed all processes with it.

Comment: OP wants to restyle the input field, this doesn't help him.

Comment: Yea, gave this a try even so.  Turned out that I wasn't able to get the file browse window to come up when I used this method.  Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine CSS and jQuery to hide elements until they're completely rendered. In your CSS file, add:

```
.element{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
```

In your jQuery script, after all the rendering stuff:

```
$('.element').css('opacity', '1');
```

The 'transition' property isn't necessary, but in some cases it's nice to have a fading effect when the elements are showing up.. When many jQuery scripts run over a site and 'everything is flickering', add this to the body element and your site is loading smooth again.